# allocating an object of abstract class type in my code

Tags: c++

how to solve this problem is said allocating an object of abstract class type in my code'LList'

```
class Graphl : public Graph {
private:
    List<Edge>** vertex; 
    int numVertex, numEdge; 
    int *mark; 
public:
    Graphl(int numVert)
    {
        Init(numVert);
    }

    void Init(int n) {
        int i;
        numVertex = n;
        numEdge = 0;
        mark = new int[n]; 
        for (i = 0; i<numVertex; i++) mark[i] = 0;

        vertex = (List<Edge>**) new List<Edge>*[numVertex];
        for (i = 0; i<numVertex; i++)
        {
```

here is problem it said allocating an object of abstract class type 'LList'

```
            vertex[i] = new LList<Edge>();
        }
```

Comment: What's `Edge` actually? I'd suspect it's an abstract class.

Comment: Well you cannot allocate an object of an abstract class. The fix is to stop trying to do that. Allocate an object of a concrete class instead.

Comment: I have no idea whether there's a difference between List and LList, you need to check it. Also, stop using raw pointers, C-style arrays, and self-written lists. C++ comes with a library, use it. Never ever use C-style casts. This fragment needs no casts.

Answer (score 1):

You don't allocate an object of an abstract class because such objects cannot be created.  (That's why they are abstract.)

Also, this looks strange:

```
List<Edge>** vertex;
```

Why a pointer to a pointer to a list of edges?  I guess what you've actually meant to write was

```
List<List<Edge *>> vertex;
```

which would be a list of lists of pointers to Edges.  That is fine, even if `Edge` is an abstract type.  Generally, we refer to abstract types via pointers or references.

I'm saying this without knowing what your `List` actually is.  I'm assuming it has semantics similar to `std::list`.